# Sending sms from Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sms

In my Windows Phone 7 application I want to send sms where the message body should contain the data from my previous page in my application. The data which i want to display is:

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Date_Start"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            date = NavigationContext.QueryString["Date_Start"];
            datee.Text = date;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Title"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            ntitle = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Title"];
            title.Text = ntitle;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Description"))
        {
            ndes = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Description"];
            description.Text = ndes;
        }
```

I wrote the following code in the button click event:

```
 private void btn_text_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

        smsComposeTask.To = "+91-9778999";
        smsComposeTask.Body = title + "," + description + "," + datee;

        smsComposeTask.Show();

        my_popup_cs.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

I wanted the result as the value of title, description and date. But in the message body i got the result as:

```
System.WIndows.Controls.TextBLock, System.WIndows.Controls.TextBLock,   System.WIndows.Controls.TextBLock
```

However i tested only in emulator. Is it possible to display the result in the emulator? Or else please have a look at my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code.it should like this.

```
smsComposeTask.Body = title.Text + "," + description.Text + "," + datee.Text;
```

please try it.